# Load dataframe from csv discarding all that doesn't follow a schema

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read from a csv file and load it into a dataframe. Now, I tried the following.

```scala
    val schema = StructType(Seq(
      StructField("key", StringType, true),
      StructField("value", DoubleType, false)
    ))
    val df = sc.read.schema(schema)
      .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
      .csv("C:\\Users\\raam\\IdeaProjects\\myPlayGround\\abc.csv")
    df.show()
```

My, csv looks like this

```
qqq
a,1
b,2.2
c,xyz
d,4.5
e,asfsdfsdf 
dd,
f,3.1
2,
,6.6
```

My output is

```
+----+-----+
| key|value|
+----+-----+
|   a|  1.0|
|   b|  2.2|
|   d|  4.5|
|  dd| null|
|   f|  3.1|
|   2| null|
|null|  6.6|
+----+-----+
```

In the 2nd `StrcutField`, nullable is false why is 4th and 6th row in my df?
Also, is their a way to create two separate df while reading so that, I can have the discarded rows in a separate file?

Answer (score 1):

DROPMALFORMED mode does drop records that don't conform to the schema (in your case records where value is non-numeric), however it ignores nullability. Have a look at these issues: [SPARK-10848](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10848), [SPARK-25545](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25545) and [this pull request](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/17293) to learn about the rationale for this. As you see it is not liked and some people tried to fix it, but without success so far.

You need to explicitly handle null records on your side then.

```
val schema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("key", StringType, true),
  StructField("value", DoubleType, false),
  StructField("corruptRecord", StringType, true)
))

val df = spark.read.schema(schema).
  option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").
  option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord", "corruptRecord").
  csv("abc.csv")

def isValid = 'corruptRecord.isNull && 'value.isNotNull
val validDf = df.filter(isValid)
val invalidDf = df.filter(!isValid)
```

`isValid` can be defined in a more generic way:

```
def isValid = schema.filter(!_.nullable)
  .foldLeft('corruptRecord.isNull)((acc, f) => acc && col(f.name).isNotNull)
```

at least when you have no nested structures/arrays.